# WPF Disable Splash Screen Programmatically

Tags: wpf, splash-screen

I have a WPF application that optionally accepts command line parameters. One of these parameters specifies "silent mode" (no UI). How can I disable the presentation of the splash screen at startup based on this parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should explicitly create an instance of the class [SplashScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and show/hide based on your program arguments, instead of using the SplashScreen build action to generate a splash screen.

You need to set the **Build Action** of your splash screen image to **Resource** instead of **SplashScreen**.

For Example:

```
private void OnStartUp(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{

    if (ShowSplashScreenArgument)
    {
        SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen("YourSplashScreen.bmp");
        splashScreen.Show();
    }

    // Do loading code here..

    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

    if (ShowSplashScreenArgument)
    {
        // Close the splash..
        splashScreen.Close();
    }

    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to not set the build action of your splash screen as `SplashScreen'. Like this you can create your own SplashScreen Window with the Image full-screen on it and show or hide it based on some parameters.